# How to change permission of a private folder from admin to wheel

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

I'm using macOS Catalina (10.15.7).

In my root directory I have a private folder names etc.
I have to create in it a file, but have no permissions for that.

If I try to get the info of the etc folder - I have no Sharing & Permission tab.

If I try to run this command: chmod 777 etc I get an the message: chmod: Unable to change file mode on etc: Operation not permitted

The owner of the etc folder is root. Maybe in order to add a file inside the etc I have to change the owner of the folder from root to wheel?
Does someone know?

Comment: use [sudo](https://support.apple.com/en-mn/guide/terminal/apd5b0b6259-a7d4-4435-947d-0dff528912ba/mac), so something like `sudo chmod 777 etc`

Comment: Don't do that, don't change permissions or ownership in the invisible root folders, `wheel` as owner is wrong anyway. There are several ways to create files in those folders. In Terminal app you have to use `sudo` to run the command with elevated privileges.